# First time Ubuntu installation going nowhere

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

After years of running CentOS, did not like the stream "option" so decided to give Ubuntu a try.  Using Mac OSX, I formatted the USB thumb drive and used BalenaEtcher with downloaded ISO exactly as described in the tutorial here.

Insert the thumb drive into the target machine, start up, and nothing but a flashing cursor.

Have looked at the BIOS settings numerous times and can see nothing out of place.

Next step?

Comment: There are three possibilities: 1) The .iso is corrupt (verify the hash), 2) The USB is mis-made (somewhat common, remake the USB stick), or 3) The target machine's BIOS has a bug that prevents mounting the Live system (Search Engine your motherboard model and BIOS version). You can also test the Live USB in a different (working) machine or in a VM to eliminate several of those possibilities.

Comment: Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   (not the link I provided for integrity check applies to older releases; you didn't provide release details so it may not apply for your system, and CD refers to any installation media, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/magnetic-tape etc)

Comment: Hash has been verified.  I have repeated the USB creation process step for step multiple times with the same result.  Will have to check out the BIOS possibility, but CentOS had no issues installing on this system.